# Call to undefined method DboSource::connect() in ***/web/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php on line 260

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to migrate a Cake PHP app from one server to another. One of the problems I run into is the error mentioned in the title.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method DboSource::connect() in
>   ***/web/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php on line 260

line 260 reads

```
if ($autoConnect) {
    $this->connect();
}
```

I really don't get what is going wrong here.... there seems to be no connect() method in DboSource and its parent classes, so why is it invoked in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `DboSource` class directly. You need to use or create the subclass.

The constructor of `DboSource` is called from the subclass by using `parent::__construct()`. For example, `Mysql` class, one of the subclass of `DboSource`, has `connect()` method. Calling `connect()` is for the purpose.

In such cases, normally, `DboSource` class should be declared as `abstract` and should have abstract `connect()` method. But it cannot be changed any more. If CakePHP team add the method, it might break userland code. Becuase `connect()` method might be implemented by using `__call()` in the subclass, for example.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11396549)

Comment: @sebastianbrosch I've updated my answer. Maybe, did I misread the question? I thought he asked "Why is connect() method called here?". So I answered "It is called from the subclass.".

Comment: yes but this could be a comment too. But now you have added a explanation and changed your answer to a good answer! +1

Comment: @sebastianbrosch I learned. Thanks for your review, and I'm sorry to waste your time.